# Flutter FFI failed to lookup symbol on Android

Tags: flutter, go, cmake, ffi, dart-ffi

I have started to play around with Flutter FFI and Golang. I tested my code and everything works fine on Windows platform, but i have issue with Android. Tried several things that I found on stack but finally failed to find solution to my issue that is failing with error message:

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown while handling a gesture: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'GetCPUs': undefined symbol: GetCPUs
```

Here is my code that is trying to check available cores on device:

Golang:

```
package main

import "C"
import "runtime"

//export GetCPUs
func GetCPUs() int32 {
    return int32(runtime.NumCPU())
}

func main() {}
```

I'm building this code with command:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o ../../cbm/libs/cc.so get_cpus.go
```

And this puth two files in my flutter project under libs folder:

```
cc.h
cc.so
```

Then in the android/app folder I have added config to the build.gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

And in the same folder CMakeLists.txt:

```
project (GetCPUs C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(
    cc
    SHARED
    ../../libs/cc.so
)
set_target_properties(cc PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

Finally this is my Dart code that tries to load library and get the number:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  int getGo() {
    var lib = "cc.so";

    if (Platform.isWindows) {
      lib = "libs/$lib";
    }

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      lib = "lib$lib";
    }

    DynamicLibrary dylib = DynamicLibrary.open(lib);
    final myFunc =
        dylib.lookupFunction<Int32 Function(), int Function()>('GetCPUs');
    return  myFunc();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter = getGo();
    });
  }
```

As i mentioned above this works fine on Windows so I assume that I have missed something on android configuration and/or something that cmake is doing with the library that I'm not aware of. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions what might be an issue.

Comment: On Windows, the Flutter runtime has access to your files (so can load the dll) but on Android the emulator doesn't have access to your file system so can't open the 'so'. When starting out with ffi, it's easiest to let the build system create your so from C source as described here https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/c-interop#create-an-ffi-plugin (Adding go at this stage overcomplicates things)

Comment: Another alternative is to add you so to assets, load it, save it to a temporary file and then `open` that. (This doesn't work on iOS.)

Comment: Actually file is loaded just file (had another error previously that pointed to the problem) but the real issue is that DynamicLibrary is unable to find function 'GetCPUs' that I'm trying to call from c library.

Comment: Check that the compiler isn't decorating the function name - use a library inspection tool to confirm its exports.